# DropDownList MVC returns null

Tags: asp.net-mvc, drop-down-menu

I've encountered some problems using DropDownList in ASP.NET MVC lately.
I want to save value of selected item to member called Wydzialy.
Sorry for not translating some names, they doesn't matter I think :)

Here is what I have:

View:

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Wydzial, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Wydzial, (List<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.Wydzialy)
    </div>
</div>
```

Model:

```
public class Student
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int NumerIndeksu { get; set; }
    public string Imie { get; set; }
    public string Nazwisko { get; set; }
    public int Semestr { get; set; }
    public virtual Wydzial Wydzial { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
 public ActionResult Create()
    {
        var wydzialy = db.Wydzialy.ToList();
        var lista = wydzialy.Select(W => new SelectListItem()
            {
                Text = W.Nazwa
            }).ToList();
        ViewBag.Wydzialy = lista;
        return View();
    }
```

Comment: Why this mix between `Model` and `ViewBag`? You should have everything you need in the `Model`.

Comment: You are only setting the value of Text in your SelectListItem, not its value.

Comment: What does "returns" mean here? Do you receive null on a server side after you post the form? In that case please post the receiving action code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your trying to bind the dropdown to a complex object. A `<Select>` only posts backs a value type (in your case the text of the selected option).

Either bind to a property of `Wydzial`

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Wydzial.Nazwa, (List<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.Wydzialy)
```

or preferably use a view model that includes a property to bind to and the `SelectList`

```
public class StudentVM
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  // Other properties used by the view
  public string Wydzial { get; set; }
  public SelectList Wydzialy { get; set; }
}
```

Controller

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
  StudentVM model = new StudentVM();
  model.Wydzialy = new SelectList(db.Wydzialy, "Nazwa", "Nazwa")
  return View(model );
}
```

View

```
@model StudentVM
....
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Wydzial, Model.Wydzialy)
```

Note you appear to be binding only to the `Nazwa` property of `Wydzial`. Typically ou would display a text property but bind to an ID property.